# What type of integral is a JavaScript array's length? Is there danger of wraparound?

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer-overflow

Here's what I mean:

I have a function I'm writing like

```
function unstable_partition ( arr, piv ) 
{
   // puts all values less than piv on the left of arr and 
   // all values greater than or equal to piv on the right side
   var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1;
   while (i < j)
   {
      if (arr[i] <= piv) ++i;
      else if (arr[j] >= piv) --j;
      else swap(arr,i,j);
   }
}
```

and I'm wondering if there's any danger with the

```
j = arr.length - 1
```

part. For I know that in C++, as an example, the integral type `size_t` that holds the size of an array is unsigned, so if that value is `0` then `0 - 1` is equal to `~0` (the largest `size_t`) which would cause a bug in this particular function.

Now, I know that I won't even have to worry about this if I do

```
function unstable_partition ( arr, piv ) 
{
   // puts all values less than piv on the left of arr and 
   // all values greater than or equal to piv on the right side
   var len = arr.length;
   if (len === 0) return;
   var i = 0, j = len - 1;
   while (i < j)
   {
      if (arr[i] <= piv) ++i;
      else if (arr[j] >= piv) --j;
      else swap(arr,i,j);
   }
}
```

but then I lose compactness, elegance.

**Does `j = arr.length - 1` pose a danger or not?**

Comment: Well, if `arr.length` is `0`, then `j` would be `-1`.  Whether having a negative value for `j` is a problem is entirely up to the algorithms you use.  It isn't going to "pose a danger" in the sense of an overflow/underflow error.

Comment: 'sup Lars. Array indexes in JavaScript are treated as 32-bit unsigned values.

Comment: @Pointy Then that means subtracting `1` from `0` will equal `1*1+1*2+1*4+...+1*2^31`

Comment: @Pointy, not quite.  In ECMAScript 5 numbers are 64-bit floating point values.  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19

Comment: @Amy yes that's true for numbers, but in the specific case of Array behavior the indexes are truncated to 32-bit unsigned values. (Array instances can, like other objects, have *other* properties that look like any sort of string.)

Comment: @Pointy, ah, you're absolutely right.  I thought that was an implementation thing, but no, it's elsewhere in the spec:  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4

Comment: So, from the perspective of a JavaScript engine, 32-bit unsigneds are used to an array's length, but when an expression involving an array's length causes overflow, that array's length is temporarily cast into a 64-bit signed?

Comment: As pointed out by @dtanders's answer, the mere fact of doing an operation coerces (casts) the length value into a signed 64-bit already.

Comment: @LarsUlrich, no.  It isn't the overflow.  Doing *anything* to the value coerces the JavaScript engine to convert the native 32-bit value to a managed `Number` value, which is internally represented by 64 bits.  It then does the addition.  No overflow is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has only one numeric type - **Number** - corresponding to a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number (the `double` type in C++), but with only one NaN value. So there is no danger of wrap-around with `arr.length - 1`

Array's "length" property returns a Number, and is restricted to integer values in the range 0 ... 2^32-1.

> Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2^32. [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects)

So `arr.length - 1` will always return -1 or 0 or a positive integer less than 2^32-2.

(As an aside, 2^53-1 is the largest integer you can safely store in a Number before operations like +1 start losing precision. Various parts of the ECMAScript standard use this as a limit, e.g. the definition of `Array.prototype.push` But the Array "length" property is further restricted.)

Answer (score 4):

`length` is defined in [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1) as an [unsigned 32-bit integer](http://es5.github.io/#x9.6).  However, any mathematical operation will coerce that into a Number, so you'll end up with a -1:

```
[].length - 1 // = -1
```

Assigning a negative number to length should throw an error.  Trying to get a negative number out of an array will return undefiend unless you've created a property with that name on the array, which is possible because arrays are just objects with a magic property that's one greater than the largest positive integer property they have.

```
a = []
a[-2] = 'something'
a[-1] //undefined
a.length //0
a[10] = 'something'
a.length //11
```

Comment: Using `-2` as a property name does work, but it doesn't affect `.length`, is I think what you mean.

Comment: I think the OP was concerned only by the initial assignment `j = arr.length - 1`, as suggested by its second code. I.e. would the subtraction result in something different than what we would expect mathematically. So it seems to me that the answer is half in @dtanders's and half in @Bergi/@Joshua's answers: the operation first coerces the UInt32 into a Number, then you end up with a signed operation for which the operands will always be in the appropriate validity range. We should highlight that JavaScript is way different from low level languages, so pitfalls like this are taken care of.

Comment: Yes @Pointy, that's a succinct way of saying what I said :)  I just like to emphasize to people that might not know better what arrays actually are, is all.

Answer (score 3):

> Does `j = arr.length - 1` pose a danger?

No. All numbers are treated as 64 bit floats in JS (though this might be optimised by the engine as long as they're small integers). When you subtract `1` from `0`, you'll always get `-1`.

As you are asking about `arr.length`, [the spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) "*Every Array object has a length property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>*". So it internally may be stored as an unsigned 32 bit integer, and on [setting `.length`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraysetlength) a value is actually [casted to one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint32), but you can rest assured that the number will fit into the 64 bit float that arithmetic is done with.